# After refresh page Redux store are set to null

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using Redux store to save the stage of my page in React js but after a refresh of the page the stored data are set again to null as default. There is a way to Redux store data are stored until user press logout button on the page.
Do you know how to save the state and after a page refresh it will not disappear ? Or there is a tutorial that I can see or read ?

Comment: check out redux-persist

Comment: use redux persist [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because redux maintains state until you refresh the page. To solve this problem you need to either write your data to **localstorage** or use **react-router-dom**

in last case state on save in your app not use localstorage.
warning. react - it SPA based framefork. please, use react-router-dom!
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start